# Getting HttpStatus from JsonResult

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am returning a `JsonResult` from my controller method i.e.

```
public JsonResult deleteStuff()
{
    //Do some stuff
    Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.NoContent;
    return Json(new {}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I want to write a test that confirms that the JSON data is an empty object and the HttpStatus is 204 but I can't get at the result with TestStack or directly from the returned object.

e.g:

```
var myResult =_administratorController.DeleteTheme(dummyId);
```

or

```
 _administratorController
    .WithCallTo(x => x.DeleteTheme(dummyId))
    .ShouldReturnJson(x =>
        {
            Assert.That(HttpResultExtensions.ToResponseStatus(x), Is.EqualTo((int) HttpStatusCode.NoContent));
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The JsonResult doesn't contain information about the status code. This information is available on the `Response` object that you used inside your controller action. So in your unit test you could simply read it from there. I guess that you must have mocked it in order to be able to invoke this controller action so you already have reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you put `statusCode` in your Json itself?

```
return Json(new 
{
   statusCode =(int) HttpStatusCode.NoContent
}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```